# Keep receiving Flickr exception: SSL is required

Tags: ssl, flickr

I keep receiving the error

```
com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException: 95: SSL is required
```

even though I have changed the call from http://api.flickr.com/services to https://api.flickr.com/services.

I changed also the keys although one is not obliged to do it according to Flickr guidelines.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Maybe an issue with the OAuth callback? Is oauth_callback url using https, too?

Comment: I have replaced http with https everywhere..

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my problem was that I needed as well to update the version of the flickr library I use from 2.4 to 2.12.